# Adding a button into lightbox using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

My lightbox code is :

```
var $lightbox = $("<div class='lightbox'></div>");
var $img = $("<img>");
var $caption = $("<p class='caption'></p>");
$lightbox
    .append($img)
    .append($caption);
$('body').append($lightbox);
$('.gallery li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).children('img').attr("src");
    var cap = $(this).children('img').attr("alt");
    $img.attr('src',src);
    $caption.text(cap);
    $lightbox.fadeIn('fast');
    $lightbox.click(function () {
        $lightbox.fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

I use it in order to display a gallery of products and when you click a product, a light box with caption and image will be displayed. I wanted also to add a button (Add to cart) but it doesn't work(Lightbox doesn't open up at all), I changed the code to:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
$lightbox.append($img).append($btn).append($caption);
```

Is there anything I need to add or something I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is 'btn', but you're trying to append '$btn'.  Reconcile the variables and it should work, assuming you've added the button object's properties...innerHTML et al.

Comment: isn't '$' is just an alias for JQuery? why does it cause problems? can you explain a bit?

Comment: In the context you're using it, $ is part of the variable name being passed to the append method.  This works fine for your variables '$img' and '$caption', because you defined those variables with the leading $.  In the case of your button, you defined the variable as 'btn' but are trying to append '$btn', which doesn't exist.  Just add the leading $ to 'btn' when you define the variable, the same as you did with '$img' and '$caption', and you should be good to go in that regard.  The code should add an empty button to which you can append a new text node or other element for content.